# Cakephp - Create a search field with a search button

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, search, redirect

I need an "onclick" action on the button so i get redirected for something like this:

```
 location/[textfield_data]
```

- http://snag.gy/wz395.jpg

I am using **cakephp** and at this moment the nearest i reached was this.

```
echo $this->Form->input('link', array('label' => false, "class" => "form-control input-medium", "placeholder" => __('Procurar')));

echo $this->Form->button('', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary icon-search icon-white' ,'onclick' => "location.href='/'"));
```

With my code, cakephp is retrieving me this:

```
/[view]?data%5Blink%5D=
```

The [view] is the current page i am in.

**FOUND THE SOLUTION**

Ive found the solution this way.

```
echo $this->Form->input('link', array('label' => false, "class" => " form-control input-medium", "placeholder" => __('Procurar'), 'id' => 'search'));

echo $this->Form->button(null, array('class' => 'btn btn-primary icon-search icon-white' ,'onclick' => "location.href='/mywantedurl/'+document.getElementById('search').value;"));
```

**Note that i didnt use any form->create or form->end, otherwise it wont work.**

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use JavaScript? Just use the `GET` method instead. You should be using `GET` instead of `POST` requests for searches any way, so the request can be book-marked etc.

You would achieve this using `$this->request->query` instead of `$this->request->data`.

```
<?php
// app/View/Locations/index.ctp
echo $this->Form->create('Location', array('type' => 'get'));
echo $this->Form->input('Location.keywords');
echo $this->Form->end('Search');
```

And then in your corresponding controller:

```
<?php
// app/Controller/LocationsController.php
class LocationsController extends AppController {

    public function search() {
        if (!isset($this->request->query['keywords'])) {
            throw new BadRequestException();
        }

        $results = $this->Location->findByKeywords($this->request->query['keywords']);

        $this->set('results', $results);
    }
}
```

I don’t know the actual schema of your database tables or your model names, but the above should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Apreciated for your help, but i didnt want to use any kind of GET since i needed a clean url without any url enconding.

Comment: If it’s going in the URL—as either a query string parameter or a segment—then it *needs* encoding regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I use a code like this

```
echo $this->Form->input('link', array('label' => false, "class" => "form-control input-medium", "placeholder" => __('Procurar'), 'id' => 'search-field'));
echo $this->Form->button('', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary icon-search icon-white' , 'id' => 'search-button'));
$this->Js->get('#search-button');
$this->Js->event('click', 'edit()');

$this->Js->buffer
(
    "function edit()
    {
        search_term = this.document.getElementById('search-field').value;
        if(search_term)
            window.location = \"/index.php/location/\" + search_term;
        return false;
    }"
);
```

Comment: I apreciate your help, but when i placed the code, the button just did not react, also there is no JS errors in debugger.